# Converting to Lower case with first letter to be upper case with Regex

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to convert some text where the first letter is changed or kept as a capital and the rest is converted to all lower case. ie
This Is SOME TEXT TO CHANGE   -  to
This is some text to change

I tried the following but \ is not compatible in Go. I still need it however in the same format.

- replace:
  - regex: (\w+)([A-Z])
  with: "\L$1$2"

Comment: You do not seem to even need a regex for this. Turn the first char into upper case and the rest to lower.

Comment: "with Regex" is almost always the wrong approach. And it's definitely the wrong approach here.

Comment: If this is homework, can you put the full text of the assignment in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments have mentioned, you don't really want a regex for this, as regexes are not really designed for that.

The problem with the standard Go library is that there is strings.Title, but that converts all words to have uppercase on the first character of each word, but looking at the source for strings.Title helps create something that works:

```
textToChange := "This Is SOME TEXT TO CHANGE"

isFirstChar := true
final := strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
    if isFirstChar {
        isFirstChar = false
        return unicode.ToUpper(r)
    }
    return r
}, strings.ToLower(textToChange))
```

This solution is not perfect (I haven't really tested it - it is assuming that unicode.ToUpper will happily convert any character), but it works with unicode.